# Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um id em html?

Tags: html, css

Oi, sou novato na programação em html e queria saber qual a diferença entre uma classe e um id?
EX:

```
#principal{
}

.principal{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Id são únicos, então é muito comum usarmos Javascript quando queremos modificar apenas um elemento, já as classes elas são generalizadas, você pode criar uma classe e reusar ela em outros componentes.

Pelo pouco tempo de experiência que tenho, diria que quando usamos [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Aprender/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basico) é muito comum usarmos mais classes do que id, já quando queremos trabalhar com [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/id) usamos mais id para interação (clique, ao tocar, etc) daquele elemento.

Entretanto é possível trabalhar com uma id e reutiliza-las em várias partes de seu [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML), não está errado, porém não é comum.

Fonte: [Tableless](https://tableless.github.io/iniciantes/manual/css/class-id.html)

Answer (score -4):

São praticamente a mesma coisa. Ambas são usadas para dar nome a itens criados no HTML. Eu sugiro você usar um id em itens mais importantes, como uma div principal e usar classes em coisas menos importantes, como divs menores e etc.